# Can an element x, be found in a sorted array of size n using n Common CREW processors in constant time O(1)?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, parallel-processing, complexity-theory, big-o

Given an n-element array, how to find position of element x in that array using common CRCW processors in constant time?

Let's assume x is not in the given array. Is it even possible to find the position of x, in array in constant time O(1)?

CREW is a type of processor which can read concurrently but can write exclusively.

p.s. this is not an assignment.

Comment: If you're always processing n elements from the array using one processor for each element, then your algorithm is O(1). However your array size must be less than or equal to n or this will obviously not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much background in parallel algorithms, but I think you can do this by having n cores and doing the following:

- Set result to "not found"
- Have each of n processors execute the following, where each processor has a different index k assigned to it: if the kth element of the array is x, set result to k.

Once all processors finish their execution, the result variable, if it was set at all, will hold an index of the array holding element k. Each processor also only does O(1) work.

Hope this helps, and let me know if this reasoning isn't valid!